# How to fix null Uri data = intent.getData() in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I want Open this link in my application, not open in browser. for this job i want use **DeepLink**. 
But when start application, show me null for `URI`.

**My link :** [Link](http://kolony.ir/1393/02/11/12/)

I write this code in manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.PostShow_page"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeWithStatus">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.kolony.ir"
            android:scheme="http" />

        <data
            android:host="kolony.ir"
            android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Activity codes:

```
// Deep Linking
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
Log.e("Deep", "Link : " + data);
```

but when running application, in **LogCat** show this : `Link : null`

How can i fix **null** for this URI and show `uri` in `logCat` ?

Comment: how about the intent, is it null ?

Comment: @Gjhuizing, when set intent in `Log.e` show me this : `E/Deep: Intent : Intent { cmp=com.tellfa.colony/.Activities.PostShow_page (has extras) }`

Comment: and what does action contain ?

Comment: @Gjhuizing, i want when go to this activity show me post content (title, image, summery and more ...) from Json and set into views

Comment: `I want Open this link in my application,`. Are you sending an intent yourself? Then why dont you post the code how you create that intent and call startActivity()?

Comment: @greenapps, i can post my codes, can you help me my bro?

Answer (score 1):

Simply instead of using getIntent() use intent parameter of onNewIntent(Intent intent) event handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Comment: Thank you my bro for your code, but show me this in logCat : `E/Deep: Link : null
E/Deep: Intent : Intent { cmp=com.tellfa.colony/.Activities.PostShow_page (has extras) }`   :( :( :(

Comment: yes, show me above logCat message :( i'am bad lucky :(

Comment: Could you tell me the contents of  `Intent.getExtras().ketSet()` ?

Comment: Maybe my manifest codes is not ok and issue is this? are this code is ok?

Comment: When write this code : `Uri data = (Uri) Intent.getExtras().keySet();` not define this : `getExtras()`

Comment: are you in OnCreate() ?

Comment: Or in a fragment ?

Comment: I write this code and show me this error : `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tellfa.colony/com.tellfa.colony.Activities.PostShow_page}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.util.MapCollections$KeySet cannot be cast to android.net.Uri`

Comment: That's normal, it's not an Uri, but the list of available extras. One of them should work for us, but we need to list the available ones. Try `for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) { Log.e("Deep", key); }`

Comment: WoW!!!! show me data from json!!!! thaaaaaaaanks. but how can i use this? my mean is how can i set this into views.  in logcat show me this : `10-13 23:27:22.450 28130-28130/com.tellfa.colony E/Deep: postID
10-13 23:27:22.450 28130-28130/com.tellfa.colony E/Deep: image
10-13 23:27:22.450 28130-28130/com.tellfa.colony E/Deep: title` , how can fetch data from postID and set title and image into views? can you help me for this ?

Comment: try `String title = intent.getExtras().get("title");` for example ?

Comment: I write this code, but not show title :         `Intent intent = getIntent();
        for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
            Log.e("Deep", key);

            title = (String) intent.getExtras().get("title");
        }`

Comment: In logcat just show me this : `10-13 23:36:46.957 8693-8693/com.tellfa.colony E/Deep: postID
10-13 23:36:46.957 8693-8693/com.tellfa.colony E/Deep: image
10-13 23:36:46.957 8693-8693/com.tellfa.colony E/Deep: title`

Comment: `String title = intent.getExtras().get("title");`, you forgot the `String`. And you shoudn't put it in the for loop. You don't even need the for loop anymore, now that you know the names of the extras

Comment: Can you send me your email my bro?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
```

You will get the exact location. It helps me hope so it helps you too.

Comment: is this an answer? can you please elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

```
  String action = intent.getAction();
    String data = intent.getDataString();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && data != null) {
        String recipeId = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }
```

Comment: show error for `RecipeContentProvider` and `showRecipe` .  how can i fix this?

Comment: due remove last 2 line -Uri contentUri = RecipeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
            .appendPath(recipeId).build();
    showRecipe(contentUri);

Comment: Thanks my bro, but i thing data is null again! because i write this code but not show me **"Deep"** into `LogCat`! my codes :         `// Deep Linking
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String data = intent.getDataString();
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && data != null) {
            String recipeId = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            Log.e("Deep", "Link : " + data);
            Log.e("Deep", "Intent : " + intent);
        }`     can you help me my bro? please

Comment: you check in manifest scheme than use that particular scheme.

Comment: I write my manifest codes and scheme ! where is my code has problem? i write manifest codes and simple link for my post. can you see this and help me? please

Comment: can you help me my bro? please

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />    <data android:mimeType="url/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
        mUrl = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

Comment: In your <intent-filter> not set host and scheme! why not use this?

Comment: i am using share url in app